# sed substitues with a single timestamp value for all the records

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to replace a word in a string with the current timestamp and for this I am using sed. However, sed updates the string with a single time timestamp value for all the 1000 records. How can I update the records so that I get actual timestamp.

```
cat toreplacefile.txt
TIMESTAMP_line1 
TIMESTAMP_line2 
TIMESTAMP_line3 
TIMESTAMP_line4 
TIMESTAMP_line5

sed 's/TIMESTAMP/$(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N")/g' toreplacefile.txt

2022-11-14T10:11:43.654_line1
2022-11-14T10:11:43.654_line2
2022-11-14T10:11:43.654_line3
2022-11-14T10:11:43.654_line4
2022-11-14T10:11:43.654_line5

However, what I am expecting is a time change atleast in milliseconds.
2022-11-14T10:11:43.654_line1
2022-11-14T10:11:43.656_line2
2022-11-14T10:11:43.657_line3
2022-11-14T10:11:43.660_line4
2022-11-14T10:11:43.661_line5
```

Comment: With the sed command you have posted, you can't get the result you claimed, because the single quotes would prohibit the execution of the `date` command. Even with proper quoting, I would not expect the millisecond value to change, until the file is really huge, since processing of the lines are most likely done in the same milisecond. Perhaps using an older, really slow computer would help.

Comment: @user1934428 Is there any other way I can achieve the change of timestamp without using sed.

Comment: Sure: Write a shell loop, read the file line by line, and for each line produce an output timestamp to your liking. If you put a `sleep` inside the loop, you can  produce timestamps which are even seconds apart.

Comment: Regarding `what I am expecting is a time change atleast in milliseconds` - seriously, why? It takes so much time to call `date` for every line that the milliseconds are just noise, their only real use being to sometimes provide some kind of indication of the order the lines are in. If you tell us what you're hoping to do with those milliseconds we can help you do whatever that is some better way.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to slow down the execution of the code yourself to see a difference in  the timestamp, e.g. using a 'while loop' to go through the file line-by-line:

```
while read -r line
do
    echo "$line" | sed "s/TIMESTAMP/$(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N")/"
done < toreplacefile.txt

# result
2022-11-14T21:59:41.875_line1
2022-11-14T21:59:41.887_line2
2022-11-14T21:59:41.901_line3
2022-11-14T21:59:41.913_line4
2022-11-14T21:59:41.924_line5
```

### Edit

One potential option without using `sed`:

```
while read -r line
do
     echo "${line//TIMESTAMP/$(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N")}"
done < toreplacefile.txt

# result
2022-11-14T22:00:01.126_line1
2022-11-14T22:00:01.132_line2
2022-11-14T22:00:01.138_line3
2022-11-14T22:00:01.149_line4
2022-11-14T22:00:01.155_line5
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU `sed` has a very convenient extension that allows to execute the result of a substitution with the shell. And as one new shell is spawned for each line of your input this is slow enough to see time differences. With your example:

```bash
$ sed -E 'h;s/.*/date +%FT%T.%3N/e;G;s/(.*)\n(.*)TIMESTAMP/\2\1/' ~/tmp/toreplacefile.txt 
2022-11-14T13:03:04.995_line1
2022-11-14T13:03:05.005_line2
2022-11-14T13:03:05.016_line3
2022-11-14T13:03:05.025_line4
2022-11-14T13:03:05.033_line5
```

That is, for a `<PREFIX>TIMESTAMP<SUFFIX>` line:

- Store the pattern space (the current line) in the hold space.
- Replace the pattern space by `date +%FT%T.%3N`, execute the result with the shell and replace the pattern space by the result.
- Append a new line followed by the content of the hold space (the original line).

At this point the pattern space contains something like (with a newline between the date and the original line):

```
2022-11-14T13:03:04.995
<PREFIX>TIMESTAMP<SUFFIX>
```

- Use the substitute command one last time to get `<PREFIX>2022-11-14T13:03:04.995<SUFFIX>` without the newline.

Note: you could try the much simpler:

```bash
sed 's/TIMESTAMP/date +%FT%T.%3N/e'
```

But this works only because `date +%FT%T.%3N_line1` outputs something like `2022-11-14T13:03:04.995_line1`. With more complex line prefix and/or suffix it would probably not. You would likely get errors or even worse (imagine what would happen with `TIMESTAMP; rm -rf *`). So, prefer the safe version.